# Background color not applied to top row of Bootstrap table created with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using JavaScript to create some HTML that renders a Bootstrap table.  Here's the code for that:

```
function displayTableData(d){

    let html = '';

    html += '<table id="my-table" class="table">'
    html += '<body>'
    html += '<h5 id="team-name">' + d.TEAM_NAME + '</h5>'

    html += '<tr>'
    html += '<td class="table-labels">Wins</td>'
    html += '<td class="table-data" id="wins">' + d.WINS + '</td>'
    html += '</tr>'

    html += '<tr>'
    html += '<td class="table-labels">Losses</td>'
    html += '<td class="table-data" id="Losses">' + d.LOSSES + '</td>'
    html += '</tr>'

    html += '<tr>'
    html += '<td class="table-labels">Points</td>'
    html += '<td class="table-data" id="points">' + d.POINTS + '</td>'
    html += '</tr>'

    html += '</body>'
    html += '</table>'

    document.getElementById('my-data').innerHTML = html

}
```

**CSS:**

```
#my-table {
/*    display: none; */
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
```

Currently, only the `wins`, `losses`, and `points` rows have the background color #EAEAEA applied.

How do I ***also*** get the top row (`team-name`) to have the background color #EAEAEA?

(I want to apply the background color to the **entire table**.)

Thank you!

Comment: Please look up the correct syntax of an HTML table. You have for example a body tag amongst other things in there.

Comment: @A Haworth, yes, I switched `<body>` to `<tbody>` as per Bootstrap syntax.  Are you suggesting that the `<H5>` tag (which is the one *not* being styled) should not be inside the table?  (i.e. this is the *expected behavior* based on the placement of the `<H5>` tag?

Comment: No it shouldn't be. And I'm  not sure what the reference to 'Bootstrap' table is - it otherwise looks like a proper HTML table.

Comment: An H5 is not allowed there. Full stop. There isn't really an expected behaviour when you force a DOM change through with JS to make the HTML invalid. It's just whatever the browser's error handling can make of the mess you've created. Write out the HTML you are trying to create. Use a https://validator.nu/ on it. Fix it. Then rewrite the JS to generate the fixed HTML.

Comment: Also, it is really usually to use a level 5 heading. Have you really got a proper hierarchy with h1, then h2, then h3, then h4, then h5 … or are you picking heading levels based on default styling instead of their semantics?

Comment: And you probably want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `<body>` and `<h5>` tags from the table. It is incorrect.
Inside the `<table>` tag You can only put `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>`.

Answer (score 3):

### HTML

The anatomy of a `<table>` is not flexible. The only content that can be within a `<table>` in descending order is depicted in **Figure I**.

**Figure I**

| Element | Content |
| --- | --- |
| `<table>` | `<caption>` |
|  | `<colgroup>` |
|  | `<thead>` |
|  | `<tbody>` |
|  | `<tfoot>` |
| `<caption>` | [Flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content) content |
| `<colgroup>` | `<col>` |
| `<thead>` `<tbody>` `<tfoot>` | `<tr>` |
| `<tr>` | `<th>` `<td>` |
| `<th>` | [Flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content) content, no [sectioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#sectioning_content) or [heading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#heading_content) content |
| `<td>` | [Flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content) content |

`<body>` is always after the `<head>` element and never the child of another element. `<tbody>` should be placed within `<table>` and if not explicitly placed within a `<table>`, the browser will add it by default. `<h5>` should be a `<caption>` placed within the `<table>` and before `<tbody>`.

### CSS

CSS in a Bootstrap environment is tricky. Usually the Bootstrap styles set by BS classes cannot be overridden by adding CSS after the BS stylesheet CSS. Typically, novices will use `!important` but using it can become a messy problem later on. It is safer to override BS CSS by [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). Simply double up the class selector (see **Figure II**).

It's also important to familiarize yourself with the [BS classes associated with `<table>`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/#overview) otherwise you'll be struggling trying to do simple styling.

**Figure II**

```css
table.table.table {/*...*/}
th.label.label {/*...*/}
td.data.data {/*...*/}
```

It appears that you wanted rounded corners on the `<table>` which cannot simply be done with `border-radius: 5px`. In the example, the CSS has all of the required rulesets to make rounded corners marked with a ✳️. The JavaScript has also been improved.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
/**
 * Render a table with the given object as content to a given element
 * within the DOM.
 * @param {object} data - Object that provides the content
 * @param {string|object} element - As a string it is a selector. As an
 *        object it is a DOM object. If undefined it defaults to <body>
 * @param {boolean} clear - If true, it will remove everyting within the
 *        element to which the <table> will be inserted into. @default 
 *        is false.
 */
function displayTableData(data, element, clear = false) {

  let root = typeof element === "string" ? document.querySelector(element) : element === undefined ? document.body : element;

  if (clear) root.replaceChildren();

  let html = `<table id="${data.id}" class="table table-sm table-bordered border-dark">
            <caption class="caption-top">${data.team}</caption>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th class="label" scope="row">Wins</th>
                <td class="data wins">${data.wins}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="label" scope="row">Losses</th>
                <td class="data lossess">${data.losses}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="label" scope="row">Points</th>
                <td class="data points">${data.points}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>`;
  root.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
}

const stats = {
  id: "table-data1",
  team: "San Fransisco Giants",
  wins: 81,
  losses: 81,
  points: 716
};

displayTableData(stats, ".row");
```

```css
table.table.table {
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0;/*✳️*/
  border-spacing: 0;/*✳️*/
  border-collapse: separate;/*✳️*/
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;/*✳️*/
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;/*✳️*/
}

caption.caption-top {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;/*✳️*/
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;/*✳️*/
  text-align: center;
}

table.table.table,
caption.caption-top,
th.label.label,
td.data.data {
  border: 0.5px solid #000;/*✳️*/
  background: #eaeaea;
}

table.table.table {
  border-bottom: 0;/*✳️*/
  border-top: 0;/*✳️*/
  background: transparent;/*✳️*/
}

th.label.label {
  font-weight: 500;
}

tr:last-of-type th.label.label {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;/*✳️*/
}

tr:last-of-type td.data.data {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;/*✳️*/
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">
    <section class="row"></section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```